# Subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_2^N$ containing many pairs of far apart vectors

Tags: co.combinatorics, coding-theory

Let $S$ be a subset of vectors in $\mathbb{F}_2^{3n}$ having Hamming weight $n$. Suppose that $S$ contains $m$ pairs of vectors having disjoint supports (that is, they are at Hamming distance $2n$ from each other). Then, is $|\text{Span}(S)| \ge m \cdot (2/3)^{3n}$?

If we take $S$ to be all vectors of weight $n$, $|\text{Span}(S)| = 2^{3n}$ if $n$ is odd and $2^{3n-1}$ if $n$ is even. In this case $m=\binom{3n}{n}\binom{2n}{n}$, and so by Stirling's inequality one checks that the bound holds (and is essentially tight for large $n$). Basically, the question is if one can beat this example.